# Embed Resource Files into C++ Executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-not-found

I'm running into a strange issue when I compile a release package for a C++ application I am writing for work. Inside the IDE(Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition), when I compile and run the application, it runs fine and finds the missing resource file. When I compile with the IDE, go into the file manager, go to the output directory, and try to run the compiled EXE, I run into an error that says "Failed to load icon from the file 'foo/bar/dumb.ico' (error 2: the system cannot find the file specified.)'

Is there something I need to do with my IDE so the resource files are embedded into the EXE so I can distribute them around the office?

Comment: 'foo/bar/dumb.ico' isn't valid , there needs to be something at the front a "/path/"

Comment: @newbie I put the full path of the resource file in my C++ class file and when I run it, it says, "Loading resource image unsuccessful." and then just stops. I'm going to google around and see if I find anything. Feel free to contribute with your knowledge.

Comment: It would be extremely bad practice to embed resources into an executable. for an icon you would have to do it as a binary data structure. It would be far easier to resolve why you can't load the file at runtime and package the icon with your executable in standard install package

Comment: can you trap what the return code is ? Verify that the file exists in that there is no typo, then check you have the correct access rights